# Why isn't `print(x[0:10:-1])` the same as `print(x[::-1])`?

Tags: python

If you define a string in Python like:

```
x = "1234567890"
```

`print(x[::-1])` prints the string in reverse order, but 
`print(x[0:10:-1])` prints nothing.

Why don't they print the same thing?

Comment: What about `print(x[10::-1])`? This will be as same as `print(x[::-1])`. `-1` is put to get the string in reverse order. So the starting index should be larger than the end. If you use `print(x[0:10:-1])`, it means `0` as the starting index and `10` as the end. It will not works when you want to reverse the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See note 5 of the [relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

> The slice of *s* from *i* to *j* with step *k* is defined as the sequence of items with index `x = i + n*k` such that `0 <= n < (j-i)/k`. In other words, the indices are `i`, `i+k`, `i+2*k`, `i+3*k` and so on, stopping when *j* is reached (but never including *j*)

Accordingly, when you specify `i = 0, j = 10, k = -1` in `[0:10:-1]`, there are no values of `n` which satisfy the equation `0 <= n < (j-i)/k`, and therefore the range is empty.

On the other hand, in `[::-1]`, `i == j == None`. Refer to the next part of note 5:

> If *i* or *j* are omitted or None, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of *k*).

Since `k` is negative, `i` becomes `len(s) - 1`, which evaluates to `9`. `j` cannot be represented by any number (since `0` would cut off the last character).

Answer (score 1):

You should know about the basic rule `x[start:stop:step]`. In your code, you put two different rules: `print(x[0:10:-1])` and `print(x[::-1])`.

When you put nothing in the `start` and `stop` index, your code will be executed using the default depends on the step. If the step is positive, then the `start` index will be from `0` and the `stop` is the length of the string. Here, you may customize the `start` and `stop` value as long as they fulfilling `start < stop`.
On the other hand, if the step is negative, then the `start` index will be from the last index of the string while the `stop` is `0`. Here, you may also customize the `start` and `stop` value as long as they fulfilling `start > stop`.

In your case, you wrote `print(x[0:10:-1])` that gives you nothing back. This clearly because you set `0` as the start and `10` as the stop index while the step is negative.

Reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `print(x[10:0:-1])`.

```
>>> x = list(range(10))
>>> x[10:0:-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

We can model `x[start:end:step]` with the following pseudocode:

```
i = start
if start < end:
  cond = lambda: i < end
else:
  cond = lambda: i > start

while cond():
  SELECT x[i]
  i += step
```

Comment: This doesn't handle `None`.